# Load new page when succesfully logged in "JSP java"

Tags: jsp

We have created a login page where a user can enter a username + password. When clicking login, we send the user name + password to a JSP file called "validateLogin"

I could use some advice in how to load a new page when clicking on the "login" button.

**My code so far of the "validateLogin"**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    <%
  String uid, pass;

  uid = request.getParameter("userid");
  pass = request.getParameter("password");
  if ("mk123".equals(uid) && "1234".equals(pass))
  {

    // sæt attributten "logget ind" i sessionen
    session.setAttribute("logged in", "yes");
    out.println("You have succesfully logged in<br>");

 // New location to be redirected
    String site = new String("http://localhost:8080/CDIO3_-_Gruppe17/ScaleWeb.jsp");
    response.setHeader("Location", site); 

  }

  else
  {
    // fjern attributten "logget ind" fra sessionen
    session.removeAttribute("logged in");
    out.println("Wrong userid or password.<br>");
  }
%>
    Try enter
    <a href="ScaleWeb.jsp">the protected page </a> or go back to
    <a href="Login.jsp">page </a>.


</body>
</html>
```

I tried to create something in the if sentence, but it dosen't really work well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've come from PHP since you're setting the header.  Instead of `response.setHeader("Location", site);` do:

```
response.sendRedirect(site); 
return;
```

Just setting the Location header doesn't seem to work with JSP.